# How do we understand $F_Y(Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

In probability, we know that $F_Y(y) := P(Y\le y)$ is is the probability that the random variable $Y$ is less than or equal to a given real value $y$. But how do we understand the notation $F_Y(Y)$. For example. If Y follows a Gaussian distribution, what is its $F_Y(Y)$?

Comment: That does not look like a common notation to me. What is the context?

Comment: Do you mean $F_Y(y)$?  Uppercase and lowercase letters mean different things...

Answer (score 3):

If $Y$ is a random variable and $G$ is a fixed (i.e. not random) function, then $G(Y)$ is itself a random variable.

For the standard normal (or "Gaussian") distribution, you have
$$
F_Y(y) = \Pr(Y\le y) = \int_{-\infty}^y \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} \, du
$$
So $F_Y(y)$ is the value of the cumulative probability distribution function at a particular number $y.$

Now look at $F_Y(Y),$ which is itself a random variable. Observe that $F$ is continuous and strictly increasing, and approaches $0$ at $-\infty$ and approaches $1$ at $+\infty.$ So for $0<x<1,$ you have
$$
\Pr(F_Y(Y) \le x) = \Pr(Y \le F_Y^{-1}(x)) = F_Y(F_Y^{-1}(x)) = x.
$$
For $x\ge 1$ you have $\Pr(F_Y(Y)\le x) = 1$ since all values of $F_Y$ are less than $1,$ and for $x\le0$ you have $\Pr(F_Y(Y)\le x) = 0$ since all values of $F_Y$ are more than $0.$

So you have
$$
F_{F_Y(Y)}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x \le 0, \\ x & \text{if } 0<x<1, \\ 1 & \text{if } x\ge1. \end{cases}
$$
In other words $F_Y(Y)$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1].$

Comment: Thanks. But how do I understand the notation intuitively? By definition, $F_Y(y) := P(Y\le y)$, however, $F_Y(Y) = P(Y\le Y)$ doesn't look reasonable.

Comment: Definitely $\Pr(Y\le Y) = 1.$ When you write $F_Y(y) = \Pr(Y\le y)$ that means that if (lower-case) $y$ is any particular number, then the probability that the random variable (capital) $Y$ is less than or equal to that number is $F_Y(y).$ But it makes no sense to say "if the random variable $Y$ is any particular number, then...", no matter what follows the word "then". In effect $F_Y(Y)$ is the probability before observing $Y$, that $Y$ would have been less than or equal to whichever number you see when you observe $Y. \qquad$

Comment: So for example, if $\Pr(Y\le 1) = 0.84$ and you observe $Y=1,$ then $F_Y(Y)$ is $0.84. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying $F_Y(Y)$ cannot be written as $\Pr(Y\le Y)$?

Comment: $F_Y(Y)$ is a random variable, that is, a function that maps the sample space $\Omega$ to real values (specifically $\Omega\mapsto(0;1)$ ). $$\forall \omega{\in}\Omega: F_Y(Y)(\omega) = \mathsf P\bigl\{\psi{\in}\Omega ~\bigm\vert~ Y(\psi)\leq Y(\omega)\bigr\}$$

Comment: @S.F : Definitely $\Pr(Y\le Y)$ is NOT the same as $F_Y(Y).$ When it is asserted that $F_Y(y) = \Pr(Y\le y),$ that means that that holds if (lower-case) $y$ is any particular number.